# AssertionError on identical tuples (Tensorflow keras)

Tags: python, tensorflow, exception, keras, tuples

```
x = tf.keras.layers.Input((2,))
z = x.shape
y = (None, 2)
print("z: ", z)
print("y: ", y)
assert z == y
```

Output:

```
z: (None, 2)
y: (None, 2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 113, in <module>
    assert z == y
AssertionError
```

Why is it giving an assertion error when z and y are the same shape?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. The tuples have different types.

```
print(type(z))
print(type(y))

Output: 
<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.tensor_shape.TensorShape'>
<class 'tuple'>
```

Answer (score 0):

tensor.shape.as_list() will give you shape in list format.

```
assert tuple(z.as_list()) == y
```